# Percent hydrogen and carbon

Tags: organic-chemistry, analytical-chemistry, stoichiometry, combustion

> A 1 g sample of an organic compound was burned in a combustion analyzer and yielded 1.42 g carbon dioxide and 0.872 g of water. Calculate the percent carbon and hydrogen in the sample. From the percentages, calculate the empirical formula for the compound.

Answer (score 1):

Your initial compound weights 1g, and it is only made of C and H. The products are CO<sub>2</sub> and H<sub>2</sub>O. In other words (the reaction is not balanced, but for our purpose we don't care):

C<sub>x</sub>H<sub>y</sub> + O<sub>2</sub> --> CO<sub>2</sub> + H<sub>2</sub>O

From the grams of CO<sub>2</sub> you can get back to the moles (and therefore grams) of C in the initial compound, while from the grams of water you can get to the moles (and grams) of H.

moles of C = 1.42 g CO<sub>2</sub> x $\frac{\text{1 mol CO2}}{\text{44.0 g CO2}}$  x $\frac{\text{1 mol C}}{\text{1 mol CO2}}$ = 0.0323 mol C
You then multiply by the molar mass of carbon, which is 12 g/mol, and you get 0.388 g.

We do the same thing for hydrogen:

moles of C = 0.872 g H<sub>2</sub>O x $\frac{\text{1 mol H2O}}{\text{18.0 g H2O}}$  x $\frac{\text{2 mol H}}{\text{1 mol H2O}}$  = 0.0969 mol H = 0.0989 g

Note that we did the same thing twice, but since we have two moles of H in water we multiplied by 2 in the second equation.
Now we just have to find the percentage: 
You get

$\frac{\text{0.388 g}}{\text{1 g sample}}$ *100 % =  38.8 % C

$\frac{\text{0.0989 g}}{\text{1 g sample}}$ *100 % =  9.89 % H

I hope this helps!

Comment: Since the percentages don’t add up to 1, is there oxygen in the compound as well?

Comment: Yes, there are some other elements for sure (oxygen, or maybe nitrogen)

Comment: Would the empirical formula be CH3?

Comment: No, CH3 would be part of the empirical formula, but we don't know the complete one since we don't have all the elements :)

Answer (score 0):

Mass of carbon =(12/44)X1.42=0.39g
So percent mass of carbon= (0.39/1)X100 = 39
Mass of hydrogen = (2/18)X0.872 =0.097g
So percent mass of hydrogen = (0.097/1)X100 = 9.7

P.S.: Please always attempt such simple questions at home; you are sure to get the answer, no?

Comment: Here we cannot conclude about the empirical formula since there are possibly one or more other  element(s).

Comment: Thank you! That’s what I thought as well. This was a question on my homework. Since the percentages I calculated didn’t add to 1 I thought I was calculating the percentages incorrectly.

Comment: Please visit [this page](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation), [this page](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/443/) and [this one](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86/) on how to format your future posts better with MathJax and Markdown.